# Contact form 7 - Redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, contact-form-7

I have two forms in my wordpress website. I need to redirect users to another page after submitting just only one form. So tried with this javascript if condition with contact form 7 ID.

```
 document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) { 
    setTimeout(function(){
        location = 'https://example.com/';
    }, 2500);
}, false );
```

Above code applied for all pages so I modified it with if condition this way.

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) { 
  if('2168' == event.detail.contactFormId){
    setTimeout(function(){
        location = 'https://example.com/';
    }, 2500)  } ;
}, false );
```

But surprisingly it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://contactform7.com/dom-events/#highlighter_756995) what you've got should work. Check the console for errors, and also check the value of `event.detail.contactFormId` is what you expect it to be

Comment: Does my code looks ok? I mean syntax? I thought Need to wrap setTimeout before if condition?

Comment: You don't need the `setTimeout()` at all, but it won't stop anything working

Comment: My client need timeout. It shows a modal after form submit. Without if condition, it works perfectly. I think error with if condtion?

Comment: Yes, as I said to check in my first comment

Comment: I console log the form ID, but its not showing. I think problem is form ID

Comment: That would make sense

Comment: Do u know how to change contact form 7 default ID?

Comment: The form ID is in the shortcode to invoke the form.

Answer (score 1):

> Above code applied for all pages so I modified it with if condition this way.

this is inefficient, you should target the page where your form is being displayed using:

```
add_filter('do_shortcode_tag',  'redirect_form_script', 10,3);
function redirect_form_script($output, $tag, $attrs){
    //check this is your form, assuming form id = 1, replace it with your id.
    if($tag != "contact-form-7" || $attrs['id']!= 2168) return $output;
    $script = '<script>'.PHP_EOL;
    $script .= 'document.addEventListener( "wpcf7mailsent", function( event ){'.PHP_EOL;
    //add your redirect page url.
    $script .= '    location = "http://example.com/submitted/?cf7="'.PHP_EOL;
    $script .= '  }'.PHP_EOL;
    $script .= '</script>'.PHP_EOL;
    return $output.PHP_EOL.$script;
  }
```

Comment: Hello, I'm a newbie to wordpress. Would please tell me that where do I need to put this code? function.php or footer.php?

Comment: `functions.php`

Answer (score 0):

Poor me. I was using an old version of contact form 7. After plugin upgrade, it works.